# Add boundry/stroke to the line drawn using the path element - svg

Tags: javascript, svg, path

I would like to draw boundary around my line drawn using path element, 
something like this

[image]

Comment: One easy solution would be using a wider stroke beneath the actual stroke. If this is not helping you please add some code.

Comment: Yup, I quickly realized it afterwards. Initially I was thinking of going forward and back to the starting point, in combination with the lighter "fill" color